# How do you use PIP to install packages upon creation of Dataproc Cluster on Airflow DAG?

Tags: python, bash, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I created a DAG that is written like this:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta, date

from airflow import models, DAG

from airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator import DataprocClusterCreateOperator, DataProcPySparkOperator, \
    DataprocClusterDeleteOperator

from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator

from airflow.models import Variable

from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

current = date.today()
yesterday = str(current - timedelta(days=1))

BUCKET = "gs://r_etl"

PYSPARK_JOB = BUCKET + "/spark_job/reddit-spark.py"

REDDIT_JOB = BUCKET + "/reddit_job/reddit_daily_load.py"

# The above two variables are examples of env variables that can be extracted by Variable

DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS = \
    {
    'owner': "airflow",
    'depends_on_past': False,
    "start_date": dt(2020, 6, 19),
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "project_id": "reddit-etl"
    }

with DAG("reddit_submission_etl", default_args=DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS, catchup=False, schedule_interval="0 0 * * *") as dag:

    create_cluster = DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
        task_id ="create_dataproc_cluster",
        cluster_name="ephemeral-spark-cluster-{{ds_nodash}}",
        master_machine_type="n1-standard-1",
        worker_machine_type="n1-standard-1",
        num_workers=2,
        region="us-east1",
        zone="us-east1-b",
        metadata='PIP_PACKAGES=pandas praw google-cloud-storage',
        init_actions_uris='gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-us-east1/python/pip-install.sh'
    )

    submit_reddit = DataProcPySparkOperator(
        task_id="run_reddit_etl",
        main=REDDIT_JOB,
        cluster_name="ephemeral-spark-cluster-{{ds_nodash}}",
        region="us-east1"
    )

    bq_load_submissions = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id="bq_load_submissions",
        bucket="r_etl",
        source_objects=["submissions_store/" + yesterday + "*"],
        destination_project_dataset_table="reddit-etl.data_analysis.submissions",
        autodetect=True,
        source_format="NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
        create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        skip_leading_rows=0,
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        max_bad_records=0
    )

    submit_pyspark = DataProcPySparkOperator(
        task_id="run_pyspark_etl",
        main=PYSPARK_JOB,
        cluster_name="ephemeral-spark-cluster-{{ds_nodash}}",
        region="us-east1"
    )

    bq_load_analysis = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id="bq_load_analysis",
        bucket="r_etl",
        source_objects=["spark_results/" + yesterday + "_calculations/part-*"],
        destination_project_dataset_table="reddit-etl.data_analysis.submission_analysis",
        autodetect=True,
        source_format="NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",
        create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        skip_leading_rows=0,
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        max_bad_records=0
    )

    delete_cluster = DataprocClusterDeleteOperator(
        task_id="delete_dataproc_cluster",
        cluster_name="ephemeral-spark-cluster-{{ds_nodash}}",
        region="us-east1",
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
    )

    create_cluster.dag = dag

    create_cluster.set_downstream(submit_reddit)

    submit_reddit.set_downstream(bq_load_submissions)

    bq_load_submissions.set_downstream(submit_pyspark)

    submit_pyspark.set_downstream(bq_load_analysis)

    bq_load_analysis.set_downstream(delete_cluster)
```

When I put this DAG in Airflow and try to run it, it returns this error in the logs:

```
[2020-06-19 08:51:40,397] {taskinstance.py:1059} ERROR - <HttpError 400 when requesting https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/reddit-etl/regions/us-east1/clusters?requestId=42674e7e-6b08-4829-9d7f-193a04e29888&alt=json returned "Invalid value at 'cluster.config.gce_cluster_config.metadata' (type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.dataproc.v1beta2.GceClusterConfig.MetadataEntry), "PIP_PACKAGES=pandas praw google-cloud-storage"">
```

So for my project, I need to install pandas, PRAW, and google cloud storage to properly run the first task after creating the cluster. I created a different cluster beforehand that installed the packages and ran a workflow template through it, which actually worked:

```
REGION="us-east1"
gcloud dataproc clusters create spark-dwh \
 --scopes=default \
 --region "us-east1" --zone "us-east1-b" \
 --master-machine-type n1-standard-2 \
 --master-boot-disk-size 200 \
  --num-workers 2 \
--worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 \
--worker-boot-disk-size 200 \
--metadata 'PIP_PACKAGES=pandas praw google-cloud-storage' \
--initialization-actions gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/python/pip-install.sh \
--image-version 1.4
```

That's what I based the initialization action and metadata for the DAG on. Is installing python libraries like this possible this way, or do I need to use an already existing cluster?

Answer (score 1):

With `DataprocClusterCreateOperator`, `metadata` takes a `dict` instead of a `str`, so you should change the following line:

```
metadata='PIP_PACKAGES=pandas praw google-cloud-storage',
```

to

```
metadata={'PIP_PACKAGES':'pandas praw google-cloud-storage'}
```